# Understanding Merge Error 001156 from ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: merge, arcgis-pro, error-001156

I have been having trouble merging point features together in ArcGIS Pro due to the error "001156." I've been looking up solutions but they don't necessarily help me out! I don't know which output value to use either...ArcGIS Pro is fairly new to me!

[image: Below is the error I get]

Comment: Check the properties of your field `assessment_notes` and see how many characters are permitted. I bet the field length is smaller than that long blurb of text its trying to put in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to my comment, "your `assessment_notes` field probably has a field length smaller than the piece of text you're trying to insert" -- if you click **ERROR 001156** from the results area of the geoprocessing tool, it'll open the help to that error topic with more information. That should be the first thing to do when encountering a tool error.

[Error 001156](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01151-01175-001156.htm) :

> A value could not be added to the output field; for example, text
> values cannot be added to numeric fields, and text values cannot be
> added to text fields if the values are longer than the field length

The solution referenced says to change the field type. In your case its probably just changing to a new field with a longer length.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but for some reason I can't figure it out on Pro.

Comment: Your screen shot. You're clicked on `comments` and I can see that field has a length of 200. Click on the `assessment notes` field immediately above and check the length.